# Why won't haproxy capture my cookie?

Tags: http, load-balancing, haproxy

I'm having trouble getting frontend cookie capture to work in haproxy. I have this in my config:

```
frontend frontend 0.0.0.0:9999
[snip]
capture cookie foo len 10
```

Then I use nc to talk directly to the server and send it:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Cookie: foo=bar
```

I get a log line, but there's a "-" where the captured cookie should be.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you send a valid HTTP/1.1 query, i.e. specify the Hostname header?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so. Do you happen to have a "Hello world" haproxy conf that captures a cookie, and an example request that triggers it?

Answer (score 2):

You're using version 1.3.15.2, but there's a cookie capture bug that wasn't fixed until 1.3.15.6.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what it was!

Comment: I appreciate that sometimes talking to yourself is the only way to get an intelligent conversation, but this does look a bit odd.